# how do test with Junit for the method AddCalcNode()?

Tags: java, junit

Hello guys How do I test the method addCalcNode with JUnit?

```
public class Add {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectNode addCalcNode(int i, int j) {
        ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();

        node.put("result", i+j);

        return node;
    }

}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse,

1. right-click the file containing this class (in the folder view to the left). Select `New > Other` from the context menu
2. in the pop-up, select `Java > JUnit > JUnit Test Case`, then click the "Next" button
3. Click "Finish". You can change some of the attributes here, if you want - they're relatively straightforward - but there isn't much need, in this case.

Now, you have your `AddTest` class. Time to write a method to test `addCalcNode()`:

```
public class AddTest {
    @Test
    public void addCalcNodeTest() {
        // get a value from our class
        Add myAdd = new Add();
        ObjectNode addedNode = myAdd.addCalcNode(1, 2);
        // test that that value is correct
        // I don't know how your ObjectMapper works, so I'll just do this to demonstrate
        ObjectNode expected = (new ObjectMapper()).createObjectNode();
        expected.put("result", 3);
        // the assert functions are the core of JUnit, for testing that your function does
        // what you want it to. assertEquals() is the most basic of them.
        assertEquals(expected, addedNode);
    }
}
```

Now, right-click this JUnit class file (in the folder view to the left), and select `Run As > JUnit Test` from the context menu.

A display of whether the test passed or failed should appear somewhere. And that's how to make and run a basic JUnit test. You can expand on your tests from there, either adding more functionality to this one test, or making more tests (just methods annotated with `@Test`).